How to find angular offset in a star tracking camera system
I am designing a star tracking camera system. This system has a camera mount which can rotate 360 degrees in the azimuth direction, and ~180 degrees in the altitude direction. I have successfully implemented this, however my issue lies in the fact that the angle of rotation for the cameras is calculated assuming the camera is horizontal to the ground.
The reason this is an issue is that the camera sits on a board which must first be aligned with earth's magnetic north (so that the device can offset earths rotation properly). This means that the angles calculated for the camera are no longer correct.
How can I figure out the relationship between the azimuthal angle, and how much the altitude angle must be adjusted in order to have the same results as if it were on a flat plane? (I am quite sure that at an azimuthal angle of 0 degrees and 180 degrees the offset is just +/- $\theta_{\text{north}}$).
Here is a photo to hopefully better describe the situation. https://imgur.com/a/star-tracking-camera-mount-fNZlBtV

As this is not my area of expertise, any sort of help, or possible terms I can research would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Why did aligning the camera to magnetic north make it non-horizontal? Did it involve a process other than changing the azimuth of the mounting system?

azimuth mounts do not have to be aligned with the north star like equitorial mounts, which rotate about that axis.  They are generally just controlled via computer.  If you did this. the mount indicators wouldn't work correctly.
